# Trouble Installing Wordpress Get PHP Not Running Answer

Tags: php, local-installation, phpmyadmin

I have seen this topic discussed several places on the internet, both in the Wordpress official forums and on individuals' blogs. Despite having worked through some of the suggestions, I am still getting the error, when I try to run wp-admin/install.php in my browser locally logged into the console of the server.

Here is what I have done:

1) Apache is installed.

2) MySQL is installed.

3) PHP is installed both according to yum, and the following works the command line, and if I put

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

into /var/www/html/index.php and point my browser to `http://localhost`

I get the phpinfo page.

4) The OS is CentOS 6.4

5) Here is the output of mysql
Server version: 5.1.69 Source distribution

6) From command line php -version
    PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

7) From /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

What else do I need to do to install WordPress?

Here is part of the error page:
[image]
What is weird is I have not installed db tables from the MySQL server into the MySQL server on this system. It says the config has a bad database entry in it, so I'll go look at that, and update the OP.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ -- met all those?

Comment: Checked and edited OP to reflect I am running the requirements, or at least I think I am.

Comment: What error are you getting precisely?

Comment: It's a page from wp-admin/install.php. At the top are bold letters PHP is not running. There is also an environment variable dump and a table of values. The table is not completely filled in. I'll go re-create the page and try to get into the OP.

Comment: The only way that message would show if your server is not processing that file as PHP script (`if ( false )`), something seriously off with your configuration there...

Comment: But the trick is what is off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access the install via a `file` url:

```
file://home/cnorton/scratch/install.php.html
```

That is not going to work. That bypasses the web server and you need the webserver to process the request and pass things to PHP, which then passes the generated page back to the server for delivery to the client (your browser).

You need to access the file *through* the server. Something like...

```
 http://localhost/scratch/install.php
```

... I'd guess, but that can vary depending on how you have Apache configured.

And I'd also recommend giving the server a static local IP (for example, 192.168.1.111)  and using that instead of `localhost`. `localhost` only works when accessing the site from the same machine that the server runs on and not when accessing from, say, a laptop or other device on the same local network.

I don't know if this URL is what you've typed in or if you are being redirected. If the latter, you have the WordPress configuration wrong somewhere-- though I doubt that since you haven't installed yet.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and update. I can certainly move the wordpress directory under html.

Comment: You shouldn't have to move anything. You just need to access the site correctly.

Comment: You're correct, and once I re-configured apache correctly, the install is running. Thanks.